# Pass arguments from a fragment to a fragment inside a tabhost

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

in my app I need to pass two strings from one fragment to another fragment, and finally to a last fragment. Basically there is an activity with a FrameLayout, in which the various fragment are replaced.

The problem is that I think I'm doing too many steps, and it takes too much time in this way.
Is there a faster way? I'm getting confused.

Here is my code:

Frag1.java

```
//...Initiate frag2...

//Pass strings as arguments
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("String A", edittext1.getText().toString());
args.putString("String B", edittext2.getText().toString()); 
frag2.setArguments(args);

//Replace this fragment with the frag2 that has tabhost in it
manager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, frag2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Frag2.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Resources resources = getActivity().getResources();

    mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);

    //Get tabhost and set it up
    mTabHost = (TabHost) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    //Get the arguments again, and pass it to the fragment that will go inside tab1
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("String A", getArguments().getString("String A"));
    args.putString("String B", getArguments().getString("String B"));

    //...Initiate frag3...

    frag3.setArguments(args);

    //Add it to the tab
    manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.tab1, frag3).commit();


    //Set content of tabs
    TabSpec spec1 = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec1.setIndicator("tab1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);

    TabSpec spec2 = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec2.setIndicator("tab2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

    mTabHost.addTab(spec1);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec2);

    return mRoot;
}
```

Frag2 Layout with tabhost, it may be useful

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#EFEFEF" >

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="60dp" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="60dp" >
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Frag3.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag3, container, false);

    //Recover again the strings..
    stringA = getArguments().getString("String A");
    stringB = getArguments().getString("String B");

//Recover TextViews in tab1
TextView tv1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

//...Do something with strings...

//Set text of them with strings
tv1.setText(String.valueOf(stringA));
tv2.setText(String.valueOf(stringB));

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Urgh tab host, your problems started there. It sounds like as you say the ui design is flawed. I would add a simple image that explains what you are trying to do showing the different steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest and easiest way of doing what you need is using `SharedPreferences`. You can store whatever you need depending on its datatype and recover it anywhere within your application.

- The reference is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
- And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) is a good example.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about it too, now that you've confirmed, i'll try it :)

Comment: Both for reputation and feedback purposes, don't forget (once you have tried all the solutions other users might have posted all along) to accept the solution that helped you most.